# Center child divs inside parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div that must stay at 100% with 3 child divs inside.  I need to center the 3 child divs, but don't know how.

```css
.parent {
    width: 100%;    
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
    
.child {
    float: left;    
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child1</div>
    <div class="child">child2 - center us child divs! :)</div>
    <div class="child">child3</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFIddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qdHH3/2/

Comment: Do the children need to be floated?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try using `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center`

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;  
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qdHH3/3/

Comment: There's one gotcha with inline-block alignment worth noting (which you may not care about): when you add it, it tends to add this annoying bit of white space between your child elements.

To get rid of that, you need to set `white-space: nowrap;` in your parent div and then make sure there are no actual spaces between your children divs in the source code (literally, `...</div><div class="chi...`). This is important if the distance between children needs to be a specific amount (if any).

Comment: @roobeedeedada Good point, to be honest this answer is a couple of years old and I would no longer recommend using `inline-block` for layout (it always was a bit hacky). Flexbox solves a lot of these problems.

Answer (score 27):

**Flex** solution: [set `justify-content: center;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to the **parent** element:

```css
.parent, .child { border: 1px solid #000; }

.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 50vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; /* To align vertically, if needed */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child1</div>
    <div class="child">child2 - center us child divs! :)</div>
    <div class="child">child3</div>
</div>
```

Another way is to exploit the power of child's `margin` property when inside of a flex parent — specially useful to center a single element:

```css
.parent, .child { border: 1px solid #000; }

.parent {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.child {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a way better solution because the children elements don't inherit the center text align

Answer (score 2):

```
.child {

    $box-size: 100%;
    
    width: $box-size;
    height: $box-size;

    display: flex;  
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
    width: 100%;    
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
    
.child {
    float: left;    
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child1</div>
    <div class="child">child2 - center us child divs! :)</div>
    <div class="child">child3</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).