# Center align divs inside parent div

Tags: html, css

My pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/IGsoe

I want to center align all divs with the yellow border how can I do that?

I tried margin:0 auto; on the parent container but that did not help.

The "items" with the yellow border should keep their percentage width. Do not change this to fixed pixel values.

HTML code:

```
<div class="table">
<div id="navigationWrapper">
<div class="table">
  <div id="left"><image width="40px" /></div>
<div id="navBar" style="width:100%; height: 100px; background-color: grey;">

  <div class="cellContainer">
        <div class="alarmTemplate">A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellContainer">
        <div class="alarmTemplate">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellContainer">        
        <div class="alarmTemplate">C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="cellContainer">        
        <div class="alarmTemplate">D</div>
    </div> 

</div>
  <div id="right"><image width="40px" /></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="navigationWheeler">test</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.cellContainer {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background:black;
}

.alarmTemplate{
  height:80px; 
  margin-top:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:10px;
  background:lightgray;
  border:yellow solid 2px;
}

#navBar, #right, #left, #navigationWheeler {
  height:80px;
  background:yellow;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
 }

.table {
  display:table;
  min-width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#right, #left, #navigationWheeler {
  width:40px;
}

#navigationWheeler{
  background:green;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091433/center-child-divs-inside-parent-div?rq=1)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To center the four DIVs set them to

```css
.cellContainer {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and center the navbar contents

```css
#navBar {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This leaves 4px spacers for each div. This can be fixed adding `margin-left:-4px;`on `.cellContainer`.

Comment: @feela I thought text-align:center does only align content like text within divs?

Comment: @msfanboy This depends on the display property, not on the tag used…

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mEx9w/) with corrected css

```css
.cellContainer {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 20%;
    /*float: left;*/
    background:black;
    display: inline-block;
}
#navBar{
    text-align: center;
}
```