# how to place a child div in the middle of parent div?

Tags: html, css

So I Have this parent div called container in which I want to put the header div and the content div like demonstrated in the picture [THIS IS HOW IT LOOKS LIKE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJfSL.png), the problem is that my content-div doesnt get placed in the middle despite me trying the "margin:auto" and "align-text: center" suggestions.

Any ideas?

Code :

```
<div class="container">

            
            <div class="header-container">
              <h1 class="element-title">{{tile.text}}</h1>
            </div>
    
            <div class="content-container" id="keyResourcesContainer"  *ngSwitchCase="'Key-Resources'">   
              <div 
                cdkDropList
                id='Key Resources'
                #keyResourcesList="cdkDropList"
                [cdkDropListData]="keyResources"
                class="example-list"
                (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of keyResources; let i=index " (dblclick)="updateCanvasElement(keyResources[i],i)" cdkDrag>
                    
                  {{item.Designation}} 
 </div>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Search how to center divs. There's so many topics on this. Other than that, you need to provide your code so others can see it.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow, please include the code in your question as this will allow us to best help you.

Comment: This will work for you => https://stackoverflow.com/a/13091463/16639239

Comment: done, pls check again

Answer (score 1):

The flex property is a shorthand property for: ... The flex property sets the flexible length on flexible items

```css
.parent
{
  background-color:red;
  height: 300px;
  width:300px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.child
{
  background-color:blue;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  
  <div class="child">
    Child Div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a shorthand for this?